# Magento Custom module for t-shirt design customization

Tags: javascript, php, magento, magento-1.9

I want to create a module for customized t-shirts design. Configurator modules consist following features:

- Product Image upload
- Text configuration on production
- Size
- Colors

For size and color, I can simply use configurable products default functionality of magento.
But by this module I want to be able to upload logo or any custom image to be applied on t-shirt and also want to have option to write text (option to choose text font and color).

I have tried to do it using jquery, but by doing so I am only able to do following:

- Input text and place it on t-shirt (product image).
- Upload image and place it on t-shirt (product image).
- Resize image uploaded in previous point.

Now I am stuck in following points:

- Drag and drop text and image onto t-shirt image area.
- Save final customization as image.
- Show preview to user.

Can any one suggest me the way how can I do this (by adopting which PHP library and javascript library, I can do this. I am comfortable with creating custom module in magento.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Please see edited description of problem.

Comment: If you are trying find in Magento2 eCommerce then Personalized Product by codedecorator https://www.codedecorator.com/magento-2-personalized-products.html is using the fabric.

Answer (score 0):

You can use fabric js library with your custom module. Or you can integrate [Fancy Product Designer](http://fancyproductdesigner.com/) jquery plugin with magento. This is paid library  based on fabric js library.